# A little cursor bug in menu on the very top of SO (and how to solve it)

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, design

There is a menu strip on the very right corner of all Stack exchange sites. That manu contains thinks like `user name`, `chat`, `meta` or `main`, `about`, `faq`. They are divided by `|`.

When you move cursor slowly from item to item in this menu, just around `|` you get edit cursor for a moment. At least this happens in Firefox. I guess this is unwanted efect and it might be disturbing - when you move normaly between menus cursor is "flickering" as it changes to edit cursor and back.

How to fix it: Simply add following code to the CSS of all Stack exchange sites:

```
div
{
    cursor:default;
}
```

It should work all right then.

---

**EDIT:** I was told that aplying default cursor to all `div`s is bad idea... So my fix code is probably dirty. The defualt cursor should be probably applied only to the particular `div` that holds the top menu.

---

**EDIT 2:** I was asked to provide the statement *why* is this unwanted behaviour. I guess that is very simple: Edit cursor icon is used to indicate (for the user) that the cursor is hovering over the **text** that is there to by edited or at least user might be interested in selecting and copying it. Non of that is the case for menus and those hyperlinks are in the fact menus. By having edit cursor there you are suggesting to the user that there is something there (in this case "chat", "main", "about", "faq" texts) that is supposed to be selected and copyied (because that is what user is used to when he see such cursor). Is that intentional ? The other think is the "flickering" when you more quickly between items.

*There is simple test to decide if it is wrong or right: Make the cursor default in those areas and roll over the menu. Than compare it with the present behaviour. What feels more right ? More natural?*

Comment: Duplicated issue in chrome.

Comment: How about that.. Never noticed it before.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait, WHAT? Applying the default cursor to all divs is a HORRIBLE idea!

Comment: @Hello71 I imagine the SO devs are smart enough to not actually do that :)

Comment: @Hello71 that is the only fix that I know of. Why is it bad idea ? I'm nob in html...

Comment: I'm kinda missing the explanation *why* you think this is unwanted. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @balpha I thought explanation would be redundant as the reason is very obvios. I'll edit my question right now to provide reasonnig.

Comment: @balpha It is there (the explanation why I think this is not desireable).

Comment: @balpha, `.lsep { cursor: default; }` can't be too expensive, and it'll make one user happy :)

Comment: @Benjol Please notice "**little** bug" in the title. I know this isn't big deal but SO tends to have realy good UI this is just my very little to help make it even more perfect. Fix is 1 line of code (2 minutes to add?) and it might improve overal impresion for few (detailists) users a little bit. Not big deal at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

`<span class="lsep">|</span>`

Wouldn't it make ONE MILLION times more sense to do

`.lsep { cursor: default; }`

?

Comment: +1 Yes it would. I did not look in the actual SO code...